# Applescript command to make window unclosable

Tags: applescript

I have an applescript program that auto opens whenever I wake my computer.

I would like it to be unclosable until I input a password into it.

Tried searching but found absolutely no sources that could further my knowledge of unclosable applescript windows.

Oh and btw i'm pretty new to applescript, if the answer is simple then don't hate:)

Pringles

Comment: applescript that auto-opens what?

Comment: I think you misinterpreted, I would like to create a (applescript) program that does not close until a question is answered. As for the program, it opens when my computer wakes.

Comment: I see what you mean, but 'does not close' is is a long way from being 'uncloseable' which would not be possible with Applescript. It could always be force quit, or merely backgrounded.

Comment: Ok, I would like to make it as hard as possible to close that Applescript allows, any chance I could do that?

Comment: Not really. It's just another app.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to make a password protect with AppleScript. My advice: just use the one Apple gives you. Using AppleScript for this is annoying and tedious. But hey, your choice. Here is a AppleScript code that only closes when you type "password" but of course you can still use any other application while the dialog is open. All it does is stay in front and acts annoying. Here's the code:

```
repeat 
  tell application "System Events"
    set txt to text returned of (display dialog "Your text" default answer "" buttons {"OK"} default button 1)
    if txt is equal to "password" then 
      exit repeat 
    end if 
  end tell 
end repeat
```